# Tailwind: using suffix instead of prefix for breakpoints

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Is there a way to customize breakpoints and use suffixes instead of the usual prefix in tailwind CSS?

Currently, we have this: `md:p-4`

But I need this: `p-4-md`

We have a large code base and we are migrating to tailwind CSS and changing all of the previous class names (like `p-4-md`) to the tailwind prefix (like `md:p-4`) would be a huge amount of pain.

Comment: Please add the HTML and CSS code to your question that you have tried so we may best assist you here.

Comment: Will changing it from `md:p-4` to `md_p-4` work?

Comment: @ChenBr unfortunately not. we have used that pattern (with suffix) for many use cases in our project.

Comment: Maybe you should think about finding a way to mass-replace all the classes with regex, just an idea.

Comment: @ChenBr Yeah. I've considered that as the last solution :)) thanks.